# Javascript array creation error

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to Javascript. I want to create an array like this from my API data.
This is what I want.

```
let consumptionDay2 = [
  {
    data: [
      { x: "0", y: 33 },
      { x: "1", y: 55 },
      { x: "2", y: 66 },
      { x: "3", y: 550 },
      { x: "4", y: 23 },
      { x: "5", y: 346 },
      { x: "6" ,y: 56 },
      { x: "7", y: 87 },
      { x: "8", y: 675 },
      { x: "9", y: 432 },
      { x: "10", y: 234 },
      { x: "11", y: 765 }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is what I tried.

```
let tempLineChart = []
let LineChartData;

for (j = 0; j < consumptionData.length; j++) {
  let tempconsumptionData = {}    
  tempconsumptionData["x"] = consumptionData[j].time
  tempconsumptionData["y"] = consumptionData[j].powerFactor
  tempLineChart.push(tempconsumptionData)
}

LineChartData= {data: tempLineChart};
lineChart.push(LineChartData)
```

Could anyone please help me to make this as above model.

Comment: what's the input?

Comment: What is the error you are facing? Please terminate each line with `;`

Comment: provide the api response data

Answer (score 0):

Going by your code and assuming your input, this should work:

```
let result = [];
let lineChartData = {
   data: consumptionData.map(item => ({
       x: item.time,
       y: item.powerFactor
   }));
};
result.push(lineChartData)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess (and I do), you want something like

```js
// just guessing here
const consumptionData = [{"time":"0","powerFactor":33},{"time":"1","powerFactor":55},{"time":"2","powerFactor":66},{"time":"3","powerFactor":550},{"time":"4","powerFactor":23},{"time":"5","powerFactor":346},{"time":"6","powerFactor":56},{"time":"7","powerFactor":87},{"time":"8","powerFactor":675},{"time":"9","powerFactor":432},{"time":"10","powerFactor":234},{"time":"11","powerFactor":765}]

const consumptionDay2 = [{
  data: consumptionData.map(({time, powerFactor}) => ({x: time, y: powerFactor}))
}]

console.info('consumptionDay2 =', consumptionDay2)
```

That is... map each `consumptionData` entry `time` and `powerFactor` properties to a new object with `x` and `y` properties.

You can then put that array however you want into other objects (like `consumptionDay2[0].data`)

Comment: `powerFactor` not `powerfactor`